Media query alignment
I have the following issue. So I have a css grid and I want when I switch to mobile version to have the headers appear on the left as a column and then on the right to have the corresponding data. As if the header as a label and next to it the corresponding data. Although, right now they stay underneath each other and the headers I am not sure how to make them appear in every row as well.
    <div
          className={styles.sectionPanel}
          style={{ maxHeight: expanded ? '1000px' : '0' }}
        >
          <div className="tableWrapper" style={{ width: '100%' }}>
            <div className={styles.orangeHeader}>
              
              <div>{t('purchased-insurances.end_date')}</div>
              <div>{t('purchased-insurances.amount')}</div>
              <div>{t('purchased-insurances.status')}</div>
              <div>{t('purchased-insurances.action')}</div>
            </div>

            {/* 1st row */}
            <div
              className={`${styles.tablebody} ${styles.tr} ${styles.hoverRow} ${styles.rowStyle}`}
            >
              <div
                className={
                  getStatusValue(transaction.status) === 'Платен'
                    ? styles.paidColor
                    : styles.notPaidColor
                }
              >
                     {getInstallmentsCountForUser(transaction, transaction.id) >=
                1 ? (
                  <>
                    {t('purchased-insurances.installment_1')}
                    {getStatusValue(transaction.status) === 'Платен' ? (
                      <FaCircleCheck className={styles.iconStyle} />
                    ) : (
                      ' '
                    )}
                  </>
                ) : (
                  ''
                )}
              </div>

              <div
                className={
                  getStatusValue(transaction.status) === 'Платен'
                    ? styles.paidColor
                    : styles.notPaidColor
                }
              >
                {transaction?.installment_1_date}
              </div>

              <div
                className={
                  getStatusValue(transaction.status) === 'Платен'
                    ? styles.paidColor
                    : styles.notPaidColor
                }
              >
                {transaction?.installment_1_amount}
              </div>

              <div
                className={
                  getStatusValue(transaction.status) === 'Платен'
                    ? styles.paidColor
                    : styles.notPaidColor
                }
              >
                {getInstallmentsCountForUser(transaction, transaction.id) >= 1
                  ? getStatusValue(transaction.status)
                  : ' '}
              </div>

              <div
                className={
                  getStatusValue(transaction.status) === 'Платен'
                    ? styles.paidColor
                    : styles.notPaidColor
                }
              >
                {getInstallmentsCountForUser(transaction, transaction.id) >=
                1 ? (
                  <>
                    {getStatusValue(transaction.status) === 'Платен' ? (
                      <>
                        <a href="#" style={{ color: '#969ca3' }}>
                          {' '}
                          <PiDownloadSimple
                            className={styles.dwnldBtnStyle}
                          />{' '}
                          Платежно
                        </a>
                      </>
                    ) : (
                      ''
                    )}
                    {getStatusValue(transaction.status) === 'Неплатен' ? (
                      <>
                        <a href="#" style={{ color: 'var(--orange)' }}>
                          {' '}
                          Платете
                        </a>
                      </>
                    ) : (
                      ''
                    )}
                  </>
                ) : (
                  ''
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
            {/* 2nd row */}
            <div>
              <div
     className={`${styles.tablebody} ${styles.tr} ${styles.hoverRow}      ${styles.rowStyle}`}
              >
                <div
                  className={
                    getStatusValue(transaction.status) === 'Платен'
                      ? styles.paidColor
                      : styles.notPaidColor
                  }
                >
                  {getInstallmentsCountForUser(transaction, transaction.id) >=
                  2 ? (
                    <>
                      {t('purchased-insurances.installment_2')}
                      {getStatusValue(transaction.status) === 'Платен' ? (
                        <FaCircleCheck className={styles.iconStyle} />
                      ) : (
                        ' '
                      )}
                    </>
                  ) : (
                    ''
                  )}
                </div>

                <div
                  className={
                    getStatusValue(transaction.status) === 'Платен'
                      ? styles.paidColor
                      : styles.notPaidColor
                  }
                >
                  {transaction?.installment_2_date}
                </div>

                <div
                  className={
                    getStatusValue(transaction.status) === 'Платен'
                      ? styles.paidColor
                      : styles.notPaidColor
                  }
                >
                  {transaction?.installment_2_amount}
                </div>

                <div
                  className={
                    getStatusValue(transaction.status) === 'Платен'
                      ? styles.paidColor
                      : styles.notPaidColor
                  }
                >
                  {getInstallmentsCountForUser(transaction, transaction.id) >= 2
                    ? getStatusValue(transaction.status)
                    : ' '}
                </div>

                <div
                  className={
                    getStatusValue(transaction.status) === 'Платен'
                      ? styles.paidColor
                      : styles.notPaidColor
                  }
                >
                  {getInstallmentsCountForUser(transaction, transaction.id) >=
                  2 ? (
                    <>
                      {getStatusValue(transaction.status) === 'Платен' ? (
                        <>
                          <a href="#" style={{ color: '#969ca3' }}>
                            {' '}
                            <PiDownloadSimple
                              className={styles.dwnldBtnStyle}
                            />{' '}
                            Платежно
                          </a>
                        </>
                      ) : (
                        ''
                      )}
                      {getStatusValue(transaction.status) === 'Неплатен' ? (
                        <>
                          <a href="#" style={{ color: 'var(--orange)' }}>
                            {' '}
                            Платете
                          </a>
                        </>
                      ) : (
                        ''
                      )}
                    </>
                  ) : (
                    ''
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>`

and the media query: 
`@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .rowStyle {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .tableWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }

  .orangeHeader,
  .tablebody > div:first-child {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    display: grid;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: left;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  .orangeHeader > div,
  .tablebody > div:first-child > div {
    flex: 1;
  }

  .tablebody {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .tablebody > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  .tablebody > div > div {
    flex: 1;
  }

  .accordionContainer {
    padding: 24px;
  }

  .checkbox:checked + .sectionButton {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }

  .checkbox:checked ~ .sectionPanel {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
  }

  .sectionButton:hover {
    color: var(--gray900);
  }

  .sectionButton {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .sectionArrowMobile {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 12px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    transition: all 0.35s;
    padding: 8px;
    background: var(--shades400);
    border: 1px solid var(--orange800);
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
}
}


The expected result is the following: 
What I have now: 
